# android compose onclick asyncimage change picture

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

Like title said it needs to update image with new picture in Android Compose, using Coil.

```
 AsyncImage(
        model = URL,
        contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {
            //Maybe here to add code?
        })
    )
```

What I need is to load new picture from link into existing AsyncImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mutable state that you update with new url:

```
var model by remember { mutableStateOf(URL) }
AsyncImage(
    model = model,
    contentDescription = "",
    modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {
        model = newUrl
    })
)
```

Comment: This is working when I got different URL. I'm trying to figure out how to work with same URL. Let me be more clear with example: 
When I click URL i got Random picture, and everytime I get diferent picture. This is the problem that I'm facing. One URL get Random pictures but it wont work in this code: here is the link: https://cataas.com/cat    try to refresh and you will see that it returns random pictures.

Comment: This is not working: 
onClick = {   model = URL  })

Comment: I will create another question that is with same URL. 
Your answer is  correct it works with new URL.